# Is there a way for me to measure the height of a block/section in a WPF flowdoc?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

So I am building a flowdocument paragraph by paragraph, and I was wondering if there was a way that I could measure the height of a block at a given time.

my code looks something like this:

```
section s = new section();

block b1 = new Block(new Run("Text here"));//add height to total block height
block b2 = new Block(new Run("Text here"));//add height to total block height
block b3 = new Block(new Run("Text here"));//add height to total block height
block b4 = new Block(new Run("Text here"));//add height to total block height

s.blocks.add(b1);s.Blocks.Add(b2)...;s.blocks.add(b4)
//measure section here

FlowDocument f = new FlowDocument;

f.Blocks.Add(s);
```

I could either measure each paragraph after it is added, and keep a running tally,

OR

I could measure the whole section, after all the blocks have been added to it.

is it possible?

thanks!

Comment: Q: Why are you building a flow document paragraph by paragraph? I've recently done some work with flow documents and avoided building the document manually.

Comment: As for your question, you can probably use the `ActualHeight` property of the Section or Block... Not certain, would have to test it myself.

Comment: hmm. how do you build flow docs?? lol. and there is no actual height property (unless i am looking in the wrong place)

Comment: Isn't there? Sorry about that then, it was just a guess. ... In my use case I have wiki mark-up rendered as html, which I parse to XAML (using an Microsoft library) and then to a flow document. I can post an example tomorrow if you are interested.

Comment: After hearing what you do, I dont think it is right for me. I am building my document from text in a database - so it sounds pretty different from what you are doing :) thanks though!

Comment: There's supposed to be a whole API for working with `FlowDocument` that will let you get character rectangles (from `TextPointer` using `GetCharacterRect`) , and even `GetLineStartPosition` -- but it doesn't seem to work, `GetLineStartPosition` always returns the first character of the whole document, and `GetCharacterRect` always returns an empty rectangle. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The FlowDocument model, based on FrameworkContentElement not FrameworkElement, does not inherit such goodness as Visibility, Height and Width settings.

The only way I have found to force measuring, only when there was no other way, was to inject UIElements into the document using the BlockUIContainer. The named UIElement could then be measured at run time. It is, to be honest, a bit of an ugly hack, but I have not found another way to this point.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```
Block b1 = new Block(new Run("Text here"));
double width = .0;

Rect r = b1.ElementStart.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);

//add height to total block height
width += r.Height;
```

The same method can be used to get the height of even the `Section`. I'm still searching for a faster solution though, but this one works just fine. I'll keep you posted if I find anything else. :)